# Formatting a field from this ="09262001" to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: excel

I have a giant .xls with DOBs, the ppl who are submitting the file are sending the DOB's with these special characters ="09262001" but I need to put them like this mm/dd/yyyy so I can upload to the database.

What I have tried:
1- special formatting the field to mm/dd/yyyy but that does not work
2- I tried doing a special format because leading zero's are dropped when I remove special chars, so I make the field 00000000 and then tried to format to mm/dd/yyyy but it is not working.

Comment: Use `DATE` to convert the parts of that string into a true date. If you need text and not a true date, then use `REPLACE` to add in the slashes.

Comment: Try `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"00-00-0000"))` and see if you get dates in correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2))
```

[image]

Then format **B1** as "mm/dd/yyyy".  To change the data "in-place" would require a simple macro.  Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DateFixer()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, s As String
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            s = Right("0" & cell.Text, 8)
            cell.Clear
            cell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            cell.Value = DateSerial(Right(s, 4), Left(s, 2), Mid(s, 3, 2))
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"00\/00\/0000")
```

Then format as desired

[image]